# extending specific services to child class in angular 4

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

If I want to use services in child class then I have to add those services in parent class also and this results in the availability of those services to all the child classes of that parent class . How o restrict this in Angular 4

Comment: Can you clarify your need. Adding a service to a parent class make the service available to child classes, so what's the problem?

Comment: I want that to be available to only to that class that really needs it and not to all the classes that doest not need it and extends the same parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try injecting the service using the providers array inside the declaration itself. For example, you can inject a service called MyService inside AppComponent in the below manner.

Hope it helps.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

For a simple example, please refer to https://v4.angular.io/api/core/Directive#providers

Comment: so I will access it directly as Myservice.getItem() like this .Because I can't declare it inside the constructor of my base class like ( private service : Myservice)  as I will have to call super with extra parameter (which is this service). and change all other constructors defined in other classes with extra parameter to their super call.

Comment: I have made a stackblitz app. Please let me know if you have trouble accessing it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-pkumxy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The service is being injected and not extended, hence there is no need to call super. You will have to instantiate an object of the service. Either try to put it as an argument inside the constructor and let DI work on its own or do it manually like in the stackblitz app above. Thanks

Comment: No problem, all the best! :)